# Why didn't Dennis see Casey when he entered the car?

Tags: plot-explanation, split

When Dennis enters the car in order to abduct the girls in *Split*, he sprays the two on the back seat but completely ignores Casey, who sits right next to him on the passenger seat. Only after she tries to open the passenger door and makes a sound does he realize that she is there and goes on spraying her too. 
Can't really explain why.

I have two possible hypotheses but none of them are satisfactory since none comes with solid proof.

1. He doesn't perceive her because she is not "unclean".
2. His brain does not perceive her because he was expecting only the
   two other girls (whom he stalked for 3 days) to be in the car.

If anyone has a clue, I'd really like to hear about it.

Comment: I can't answer this question, but I can almost assuredly say it's not reason #1, as we, along with Dennis and most importantly The Beast, don't realize she's not "unclean" until the very end.  When he sees the scars on her and realizes her past has been troubled.

Answer (score 6):

He does see her, but simply ignores her. She's not reacting the same as the girls in back, who immediately confront him. She simply sits there, not moving and not saying anything.

She doesn't give him a reason to spray her until she makes the move to open the door.

Comment: 1. His gaze passes over Casey when he turns her way, we never see him acknowledge her existence in the car before she makes a sound.
2. Only one of the girls in the back confronts him, nevertheless he sprays them both (yet, not all three).

Comment: But both are staring accusingly at him. Casey is just frozen in fear. I doubt he would've sprayed her if she hadn't moved